# serially connected current source and resistor

Tags: current, resistors, current-source

In source conversion we can simplify circuit by shorting resistor in case of resistor and current source are serially connected and open resistor in case of voltage source and resistance are parallel y connected. But in case of mesh analysis how I calculate the voltage drop in resistor if the resistor and current source is serially connected? do I short the resistance like we do in source conversion or just multiply the current source value with resistance to calculate voltage drop? e.g: mesh analysis in loop 1 where 4 amp current and R4 resistor are serially connected. [image: circuit]

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try superposition.

Short all the voltage sources and set them to 0v. Open all the current sources and set them to 0A.

Then one at a time, allow each source to excite the circuit of resistors by itself.

Then add all the results algebraically.

Comment: I know what is super position theorem. But i want to solve it with mesh analysis or nodal analysis. But the problem is I tried several times with mesh and node analysis but didn't get the correct answer.

Comment: The procedure depends on whether you want to do mesh or nodal analysis. In neither case you need to perform any simplifications to obtain the result. The simplest approach is to solve this problem by inspection since the voltage drop across R3 can be calculated easily and then you have the node voltage of the upper node.